# Meaning of "about" in this context

Tags: meaning, context

*J. R. R. Tolkien* wrote in chapter III in *The Hobbit* the following phrase:

> “There were moths fluttering about,”

I know how to use the word *about* in most contexts. In this I don't understand what is the meaning of the word, what is his function.

Comment: Did you consult a dictionary?

Comment: Yes... I did and didn't help.

Comment: When you looked at the dictionary, how many different definitions for the adverb form were there?  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about) has six, and three of the six give you a sense of the meaning in your quote.

Comment: I think because I saw it in the part of prepositions, sorry. The answer of ServalSpots was more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/about) (No. 16)

> from one place to another; in this place or that:
>       *to move furniture about; important papers strewn about.*

Comment: Nice answer.  If I might suggest an improvement -- add a note distinguishing this adverbial usage from the prepositional.